# ¿Cómo funciona la nueva etiqueta prioritaria en Google XML Sitemaps?

Tags: sitemap

bueno mi pregunta es si la etiqueta de prioridad en Google XML Sitemaps aún tiene algún valor? ¿Es necesario agregar o podemos Omitir?

```
<url>
  <loc>http://misitio.com/</loc>
  <lastmod>2018-04-29T21:50:05+00:00</lastmod>
  <!--<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>-->
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

¿El segundo sitio web de mi Cliente tiene un mapa del sitio XML actualizado con todas las páginas con una etiqueta de prioridad del 100%? Bueno, mi pregunta es si cambio la prioridad de algunas de las páginas al 80% o al 60%. ¿Lastimaría esas páginas Ranking o alguna visita?

Una ultima duda esta etiqueta se puede omitir, o es necesario usarlo, en el sitio las url son fijas no existen nuevas url, para que se realice un analices por los buscadores cada mes.

```
<!--<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Desde el sitio oficial [sitemaps (English)](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) encontrara todos los Formato `XML` de `Sitemaps`, donde se especifica detalladamente cuales son las etiquetas requeridas y opcionales.

### Respuesta a su pregunta (explicación).

La prioridad de esta `URL` en relación con otras `URL` en su sitio. Los valores válidos van de `0.0` a `1.0`. Este valor no afecta la forma en que se comparan sus páginas con las de otros sitios; solo permite a los motores de búsqueda saber qué páginas considera más importantes para los rastreadores.

La prioridad predeterminada de una página es `0.5`.

Tenga en cuenta que la prioridad que asigne a una página no influirá en la posición de sus `URL` en las páginas de resultados de un motor de búsqueda. Los motores de búsqueda pueden usar esta información al seleccionar entre las `URL` en el mismo sitio, por lo que puede usar esta etiqueta para aumentar la probabilidad de que sus páginas más importantes estén presentes en un índice de búsqueda.

Además, tenga en cuenta que asignar una alta prioridad a todas las `URL` en su sitio no es probable que lo ayude. Dado que la prioridad es relativa, solo se usa para seleccionar entre las `URL` en su sitio.

El uso de la etiqueta `<priority>` y `<changefreq>` son Opcionales, puede usted comprobarlo en el [enlace enlazado](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).